# css error for safari browser

Tags: css, safari

css error for safari browser. Sometime it has no error but most of the time, it has.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'ts not an error but a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning as there is no CSS symbol as `$`.

The browser console does not understand that your code is in SCSS. Meanwhile your SCSS code has also not been properly compiled into CSS or you should not be loading your SCSS code in your website.

In either case, this is a warning and won't hinder the loading of your web page.